# Bessel Function Integral with sin argument

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I would like to find if possible a solution (closed form) or approximation for the following integral:
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}J_{0}\left(\alpha \sin\theta_{k}\right)J_{0}\left(\alpha \sin\theta_{j}\right)\cos\left[\gamma \left(\cos\theta_{j}-\cos\theta_{k}\right)\right]\sin^{3}\left(\theta_{k}\right)\sin^{3}\left(\theta_{j}\right)d\theta_{k}d\theta_{j}$$

where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are positive real constants.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you expect a closed form solution to exist?

Comment: That integral comes from a system analyzed in a x-z plane. I have solved the same system in a plane x-y obtaining  a closed expression form for a little different integral....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to play with it
and see if anything happens.

Turns out that
this can be represented
in terms of two simpler integrals.
I reached a point where
I can't go further.
I'll enter what I have done
in hopes that it
might be useful to
someone else.

First I'll make it easier to type,
changing
$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}J_{0}\left(\alpha \sin\theta_{k}\right)J_{0}\left(\alpha \sin\theta_{j}\right)\cos\left[\gamma \left(\cos\theta_{j}-\cos\theta_{k}\right)\right]\sin^{3}\left(\theta_{k}\right)\sin^{3}\left(\theta_{j}\right)d\theta_{k}d\theta_{j}$
into

$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)J_{0}(a \sin u)\cos\left[c (\cos u-\cos v)\right]\sin^{3}v\sin^{3}udvdu
$

(I used MacDown to do the editing.)

Bring out the terms
independent of $v$ gives

$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)\cos(c (\cos u-\cos v))\sin^{3}vdvdu
$

Using
$\cos(c (\cos u-\cos v))
=\cos(c\cos u)\cos(c\cos v)+\sin(c \cos u)\sin(c\cos v)
$
this becomes

$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)
(\cos(c\cos u)\cos(c\cos v)+\sin(c \cos u)\sin(c\cos v))
\sin^{3}vdvdu
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)
\cos(c\cos u)\cos(c\cos v)
\sin^{3}vdvdu
+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)
\sin(c \cos u)\sin(c\cos v)
\sin^{3}vdvdu
=I_1+I_2
$

Looking at the
two integrals,
$I_1
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)
\cos(c\cos u)\cos(c\cos v)
\sin^{3}vdvdu\\
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u\cos(c\cos u)
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)
\cos(c\cos v)
\sin^{3}vdvdu\\
=\left(
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u\cos(c\cos u)du
\right)^2\\
=I_3^2
$

and

$I_2
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)
\sin(c \cos u)\sin(c\cos v)
\sin^{3}vdvdu\\
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\sin(c \cos u)
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin v)
\sin(c\cos v)
\sin^{3}vdvdu
=\left(
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u
\sin(c \cos u)du
\right)^2\\
=I_4^2
$

where

$I_3
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u\cos(c\cos u)du
$

and

$I_4
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}u\sin(c\cos u)du
$

Noting that
$\cos(c\cos u)+i\sin(c\cos u)
=e^{ic\cos u}
$,

we can write

$I_3+iI_4
=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}
J_{0}(a \sin u)\sin^{3}ue^{ic\cos u}du
$.

This simplifies the original problem,
but,
at this point
I have no idea
what else to do.

So I'll leave it at this.

Comment: Thanks Marty. Maybe any suggestion to use an approximation form...

Comment: What are typical values of a and c? You might be able to use some approximation or expansion of $J_0$.

Comment: One possibility is a=c=pi*m where m>0 and integer.

Comment: Then you might be able to use the asymptotic forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms